# C# and gRPC - How to create a pool of connections?

Tags: c#, grpc

According to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/performance?view=aspnetcore-7.0 to help solve performance issues, they indicate to create pool of connections when using .NET Core 3.1. Can anyone provide an example of how this can be implemented?

Not sure if it is possible, but I would like to instantiate the connections on the server before the clients connects.

Comment: Don't use .NET Core 3.1 to begin with. [It reached End Of Life last year](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core). The oldest supported .NET (Core) version is .NET 6. That's a Long Term Support version supported until November 2024.

Answer (score 3):

Step one: don't use .NET 3.1, it is out of support

Step two: enable `SocketsHttpHandler.EnableMultipleHttp2Connections` (available in .NET 5 and above) - job done

Comment: Small side note is to use .NET 6 since it is the latest LTS (long term support) that is available.